# spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.sources disables resolution of profile-specific ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud, configmap, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I'm trying to adapt my Spring boot application to k8s environment and want to use ConfigMaps as property sources.
I faced that if I'm using

```
      kubernetes:
        config:
          sources:
            - name: application-config
```

for application with name `appName` then any other ConfigMaps with Spring cloud kubernetes convention names like `appName-kubernetes` or `appName-dev` is silently ignored. Looks like listed sources in `config.sources` overrides and disables usage of any other PropertySources from ConfigMaps. 
I'm forced to use specific name for ConfigMap ('application-config' in sample above).

So question is - how (if) can I specify both `config.sources` and simultaneously have ConfigMaps with names `appName-*` picked up correctly?

Comment: I wrote or refactored the vast majority of that code in spring-cloud-kubernetes, but I am really confused on what you are trying to ask about.  It seems from your answer that you have a config map - `A` and an application name `B`, and you expect to have loaded `A-kubernetes`, `B-kubernetes`, `A` and `B`, that is 4 config maps (or more depending on how many profiles you have), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging through ConfigMapPropertySource achieved this by

```
    kubernetes:
      config:
        sources:
          - name: application-config
          - name: @project.artifactId@
        name: @project.artifactId@
```

Now it loads `application-config`, `application-config-kubernetes`, `appName-kubernetes` and other profile-specific ConfigMaps.

Comment: I think I understood what you are asking about here, and yes - this is how you would achieve it. Note that you do not need `kubernetes.config.name: @project.artifactId@`, as this acts as a "default" value when `kubernetes.config.sources[].name` is not present.